# React useState hook affecting default variable used in state regardless spread operators, Object.assign and etc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, use-state

I am experienced js/React developer but came across case that I can't solve and I don't have idea how to fix it.

I have one context provider with many different state, but one state looks like following:

```
const defaultParams = {
  ordering: 'price_asc',
  page: 1,
  perPage: 15,
  attrs: {},
}

const InnerPageContext = createContext()

export const InnerPageContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [params, setParams] = useState({ ...defaultParams })

  const clearParams = () => {
    setParams({...defaultParams})
  }

  console.log(defaultParams)

  return (
    <InnerPageContext.Provider
      value={{
        params: params,
        setParam: setParam,
        clearParams:clearParams
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </InnerPageContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

I have one button on page, which calls `clearParams` function and it should reset params to default value.
But it does not works

Even when i `console.log(defaultParams)` on every provider rerendering, it seems that `defaultParams` variable is also changing when state changes

I don't think it's normal because I have used `{...defaultParams}` and it should create new variable and then pass it to `useState` hook.

I have tried:

```
const [params, setParams] = useState(Object.assign({}, defaultParams))
const clearParams = () => {
  setParams(Object.assign({}, defaultParams))
}
```

```
const [params, setParams] = useState(defaultParams)
const clearParams = () => {
  setParams(defaultParams)
}
```

```
const [params, setParams] = useState(defaultParams)
const clearParams = () => {
  setParams({
    ordering: 'price_asc',
    page: 1,
    perPage: 15,
    attrs: {},
  })
}
```

None of above method works but 3-rd where I hard-coded same object as `defaultParams`.
The idea is to save dafult params somewhere and when user clears params restore to it.
Do you guys have some idea hot to make that?

**Edit:**
This is how I update my params:

```
const setParam = (key, value, type = null) => {
    setParams(old => {
      if (type) {
        old[type][key] = value
      } else old[key] = value
      console.log('Params', old)
      return { ...old }
    })
  }
```

Comment: I think we need a bit more context of how you use this. Given [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-brook-d4onw?file=/src/App.tsx) (admittedly rather crude) example, everything seems to work as expected. So I would assume the problem lies in code not shown here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please show how you update the "params".

if there is something like this in the code "params.attrs.test = true" then defaultParams will be changed

if `old[type]` is not a simple type, it stores a reference to the same object in defaultParams. `defaultParams.attrs === params.attrs`. Since during initialization you destructuring an object but not its nested objects.

the problem is here: `old[type][key] = value`

solution:

```
const setParam = (key, value, type = null) => {
    setParams(old => {
      if (type) {
        old[type] = {
          ...old[type],
          key: value,
        }
      } else old[key] = value
      return { ...old }
    })
  }
```

Comment: you saved me friend This happened to me in a component